# Calling a php page from an html-form action, but causing a "404 Not Found" error

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, openshift

I have created an HTML form which calls a php page (function) when submitted:

```
<form name="business" action="create-account-and-profile.php" method="POST"> 
<table> 
<tbody> 
  ....
```

I have made sure that create-account-and-profile.php is in the same directory. The php file is a form data processor which starts as follows:

```
require_once (ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/user.php");
if (isset($_POST['personal_email_id'])) {
    $email_id = $_POST['personal_email_id'];
.......
```

For some reason unknown to me, when the form is submitted, a “404 not found” error was generated.

This is on a WORDPRESS platform, hosted in the Openshift environment.

I searched and reviewed relevant posts on this and WORDPRESS forums.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

JZ

Comment: Are you making a plugins?

Comment: No, simply developing a simple form and a form processor.

Answer (score 0):

You must check that create-account-and-profile.php is in the same relative path of HTML page containing the form. e.g.:

if you form is in

**example.com/subdir**/form.html

the php file must be in

**example.com/subdir**/create-account-and-profile.php

Comment: Yes, I have made sure that they are in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the **create-account-and-profile.php** page simply by typing the URL into your browser? If you can't reach the page that way the problem is probably not connected to the POST request.

Comment: I thought about this, and did not know what should be the url. I tried a few speculated urls, all of them gave me the same "404 Not Found" error.

Comment: I don't work with Wordpress, however Fil's answer seems to be true. If you can't reach the page by simply opening it with your browser, your form definitely can't either. That means it's a Wordpress related issue, hope I could at least help you a little bit...

Answer (score 0):

I think that not possible with wordpress since wordpress will route all http request to wp-content using internal functions of via httacess.

Comment: I also searched previous posts on WORDPRESS support forum. Seems to me that this is possible from posts on that forum.

Comment: Posible if using php outside wordpress wp-admin/ is the core of wordpress its better not to mess around it because anytime, they have updates, it will affect your site in the future.